# How is this font displaying the same letter in different forms?

Tags: fonts

I'm using a font that displays letters in a random way (not limited to uppercase and lowercase) and I'm not able to understand why.

In the following images, the same uppercase G is rendered differently at different positions:

[image: position 0]

[image: position 1]

[image: position 2]

[image: position 3]

Try it yourself [here](https://www.fonts.com/font/pintassilgoprints/stick-a-round/stick-a-round). (select the web font variant)

I'm using Ubuntu and I tested it on Firefox and Chromium. In fact, the same behavior occurs in LibreOffice Write (after installing the font locally).

How is this done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an Open Type feature called [Random Contextual Alternates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms745109(v=vs.100)#random-contextual-alternates):

> Random contextual alternates provide multiple substitute glyphs for a single character. When implemented with script-type fonts, this feature can simulate handwriting by using of a set of randomly chosen glyphs with slight differences in appearance.

Open Type comes with features such as [contextual ligatures, and stylistic sets](https://typofonderie.com/font-support/opentype-features/). If you look at the font's OT version's details on the page you posted you'll see [all of the features it uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1oz4.png).